# gwt mosaic preventing deploy

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-mosaic

I have a gwt project that uses gwt-mosaic.

Here is the error message I get:

> Compiling module com.athena.Athena
>   Refreshing module from source
>         Validating newly compiled units
>            Removing units with errors
>               [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/table/DataTable.java'
>                  [ERROR] Line 64: The method onMouseClick(Event) is
>   undefined for the type DataTable
>               [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/Table.java'
>                  [ERROR] Line 320: The method isPageLoading() is undefined
>   for the type
>   PagingScrollTable2
>               [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-incubator-trunk-r1684.jar!/com/google/gwt/gen2/picker/client/SliderBar.java'
>                  [ERROR] Line 120: The method addSliderBarDefault() is
>   undefined for the type Gen2CssInjector
>            Removing invalidated units
>               [WARN] Compilation unit 'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/ListBox.java'
>   is removed due to invalid
>   reference(s):
>                  [WARN] jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/table/DataTable.java
>               [WARN] Compilation unit 'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/ComboBox.java'
>   is removed due to invalid
>   reference(s):
>                  [WARN] jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-mosaic/gwt-mosaic-r951.jar!/org/gwt/mosaic/ui/client/ListBox.java
>   [ERROR] Errors in
>   'jar:file:/Users/kevmo/AthenaLibs/gwt-incubator-march-02-2009.jar!/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/GlassPanel.java'
>         [ERROR] Line 91:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.widgetideas.client.impl.GlassPanelImpl'
>   cannot be abstract    [ERROR] Cannot
>   proceed due to previous errors

When in hosted mode, I get this error, but everything in my app appears to function as normal.  However I cannot deploy to GAE because of these errors.  I've tried downloading fresh jar files and deleting them and adding them back, but no luck.  It must be something with my environment, as my co-worker uses the same project from our SVN server without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your Jar. Try to get working project from [gwt-mosaic](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mosaic/) project and [use his libs](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mosaic/source/browse/#svn/trunk/lib). As I know there were problems with gwt-dnd and that guy had to do something with gwt-dnd to make it work.

Comment: the problem was with the jars, i had to use a special version of gwt-incubator.  Thanks!!